# Ajax Deleting Images if form does not submitted

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I am Uploading Images with ajax. 
I want to delete images in case if user leave the page without submitting the form.

Also what is the Best practice to handle this scenario?

Comment: for guys giving minus points on this post, it is easier for them to press minus button rather than posting answer

Answer (score 1):

When user has any action which changes data image => set flag => TRUE
If user leaves page, you check action close tab and alert to user if flag == TRUE